# Cisco 877 configuration with multiple firewalls behind in parallel using public IP's

Tags: firewall, cisco, router, adsl

I would like to ask how I can configure my cisco 877 adsl router to have multiple firewalls installed in parallel behind the cisco 877 router. I have enclosed a diagram of what I am trying to achieve. I have a multiple public IP's and I wish to assign a public ip to the cisco 877 router and each firewall behind the router. Each firewall is from a different vendor and is being used for training purposes.

- ISP Gateway IP >> Cisco 877 Public IP 1 >> FW1 Public IP 2 >> FW1 LAN IP Subnet 1
- ISP Gateway IP >> Cisco 877 Public IP 1 >> FW2 Public IP 3 >> FW2 LAN IP Subnet 2
- ISP Gateway IP >> Cisco 877 Public IP 1 >> FW3 Public IP 4 >> FW3 LAN IP Subnet 3

I have a diagram but could not include as it is my first post.

My aims are to:

- Manage the 877 router from Network 1 only using secure protocols i.e. ssh and https
- Nat performed by each firewall
- Create a SSL/IPSEC VPN to each firewall for testing.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: It's hard to understand from your post what are you intended to do. Cisco 877 actually has only one WAN interface and 4 dot1q vlans, some of which are reserved, so you probably can configure only 2 WAN links (one ADSL and one ethernet). It looks like you don't need an intermediate router, but all you need is a switch between your ISP and other routers.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2211778/Firewall%20Diagram.JPG

Comment: Sorry I meant to post a link to a diagram.

Comment: This decent diagram is clearly missing the network prefix indication. Is this set of public IP addresses routed to your current IP address (which is currently used by the C877), or is it from the same subnet as this current C877 IP ?

Comment: The IP's are from the same subnet as the C877. I have updated the diagram (not real ip's used). https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2211778/Firewall%20Diagram-Updated.JPG Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can try to bridge the vlan1 interface with your ISP WAN interface then.